# Vite React project not recognizing tailwindcss classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I tried the other solutions on Stack Overflow and also followed the tailwind docs on the subject but still haven't got any luck. I get the warning - "warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration%22). I checked the content array in my tailwind.config.js file and it looks to be correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my file structure

[image]

This is my tailwind.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html", // <= add this
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", // <= no spaces
  ],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This is my postcss.config.js file

```
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

This is my main.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

This is my App.jsx file

```
import './App.css'

function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
      Hello world!
    </h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is my index.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

This is my vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "polyprototype",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: sharing details of what triggers the warning/error, and other configurations like your `vite.config.js`, `package.json` would help trace the problem

Comment: "This is my App.js file" No `App.js` appears in the image of the file structure – consider adding it to the `src` folder to have Tailwind scan its content.

Comment: @Wongjn OP was most likely referring to `App.jsx` since it's imported like that in `main.jsx`, and `App.jsx` appears in the folder structure

Comment: @Airah The warning gets triggered whenever I run "npm run dev". Whenever I change the class name to a tailwind class and save the file, nothing is changing on my app. I am not sure what is causing it because I followed the tailwindcss guide exactly. I also added my vite.config.js and package.json files above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: from the configs you've provided, everything looks correctly set up and the tailwind classes should work correctly. I have a similar setup and I don't get any warnings (my `postcss` file has a different extension though, to accomodate the module config I used. 
Unless there are extra configs that you have not added above, but in any case, it may simply be a case of you reinstalling tailwind or restarting the dev server @RobertWilliamson